# Webpage: Load centered at specific point

Tags: html, css, alignment, pageload

I am making a website with fixed positions and where my div configuration is very unorthodox. The current size of the page is 1450 x 900. What I want to do is to somehow make the page load with a starting point different than top:0; left:0. So, assume that you have a resolution of 1024 x 768 in your browser, I would like the page to load in such a way where you don't see the first 1024 pixels (out of the 1450) and the first 768 pixels (out of the 900) but rather, let's say the 300-1324px in width and the 100-868px in height.

I hope you understand what I am trying to describe, if not please do ask me for clarifications.

Any help is much appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using javascript:

```
var xcoord = 100,
ycoord = 300;
window.scroll(xcoord, ycoord);
```

The coordinates are where you want the top-left corner of the browser window to load.

Comment: This is probably what I need, but the screen does not stay there. If I add an alert("sth"); I can see that when the alert pops the screen is at the right place and then when, I remove the alert function, it does not work again. Ideas why?